# HTML Assignment to a php variable

Tags: php

I am working on an email template. My requirement is to take the html that I get from a textbox and assign to a php variable and pass it as an argument to the Constant contact web service. Is there any way that can make the html assignable to a string variable i.e., converting all the double quotes to single quotes etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I've understood you right, but I feel you need this:)

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<style>
...
</style>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<table cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
       <th>title_1</th>
       <th>title_2</th>
       <th>title_3</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>v_1</td>
       <td>v_2</td>
       <td>v_3</td>
     </tr>
</table>
<?php

$HTML = ob_get_clean();
```

Now you have all html-text in the php-variable. 
Sorry, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is coming from a textbox, it is *already* going to be in a variable.

```
$someOtherVariable = $_POST['name_of_text_box'];
```

The PHP manual section on [strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) describe the various ways you can construct strings, including how to escape characters (such as quotes) that might otherwise has special meaning in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert anything to just to assign it to PHP variable - the PHP variable can contain any string including any qoutes, < > etc. The question is what would you want to do with the HTML code next. You may e.g. want to convert the html special chars to the html entities by htmlspecialchars() function.